# How do I add an if statement to this specific jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I will refer to Buttons 1-2 with B1 and B2 to explain my problem.

Clicking on B1 will open the list.
Clicking on B2 while B1 is open, will close B1 and open B2.

Here's the problem:
Clicking on B1 while B1 is open, will close and open B1 again.
I want it to close when clicked, IF it was open. How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-container").slideUp('slow')
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-container').slideDown('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 1</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">1.1</a>
      <a href="#">1.2</a>
      <a href="#">1.3</a>
      <a href="#">1.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 2</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">2.1</a>
      <a href="#">2.2</a>
      <a href="#">2.3</a>
      <a href="#">2.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 3</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">3.1</a>
      <a href="#">3.2</a>
      <a href="#">3.3</a>
      <a href="#">3.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: check for state before doing something. ex: if $(".dropdown-container").is(":visible") {
slidedown()
} else 
{
slideUp()
}

Comment: @Raimonds, Why not simple [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1dgf7mp7/

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks!

Comment: @Satpal for the same reason you don't always use ternary if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude current element's container, and use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {    
    var childCointainer = $(this).find('.dropdown-container');
    $(".dropdown-container").not(childCointainer).slideUp('slow'); 
    
    childCointainer.slideToggle('slow'); 
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 1</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">1.1</a>
      <a href="#">1.2</a>
      <a href="#">1.3</a>
      <a href="#">1.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 2</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">2.1</a>
      <a href="#">2.2</a>
      <a href="#">2.3</a>
      <a href="#">2.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 3</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">3.1</a>
      <a href="#">3.2</a>
      <a href="#">3.3</a>
      <a href="#">3.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .not selector to exclude the clicked drop down, from  sliding up

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-container');
    $dropdown.slideToggle('slow');
    $(".dropdown-container").not($dropdown).slideUp('slow');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 1</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">1.1</a>
      <a href="#">1.2</a>
      <a href="#">1.3</a>
      <a href="#">1.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 2</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">2.1</a>
      <a href="#">2.2</a>
      <a href="#">2.3</a>
      <a href="#">2.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown btn">
    <span>Button 3</span>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">3.1</a>
      <a href="#">3.2</a>
      <a href="#">3.3</a>
      <a href="#">3.4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```